# Google Spreadsheets formula should I use for highlight more than an 1hour passed between cells?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need help with a Google spreadsheet formula. This is what I'm trying to do:

Highlight the cells in “Conditional Formatting” where the time spent between 2 cells is more than 60min.  In this case the B cell should be highlighted because the activity stopped for more than an hour.

[image: activity stopped for more than an hour]

Which formula to use?  I try to change time format to number and compare between the cells but no success. Any idea please?

Comment: All the time is for the same day, the B is the 11:59:00    The downtime between 10:11:32 and 11:59:00 is more than 60 min so the cell 11:59:00 should be highlighted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the possibility of conflicting rules, clear all conditional formatting from ColumnA (**assumed** because OP won't say where the data is), select it and apply a **Custom formula is** of:

```
=and(A2<>"",A1>1/24+A2)
```

Select your format and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

For your locale you might need `;` rather than `,`.

[AND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301) (used here to address blank cells).

With one day being one unit to Google Sheets, `1/24` is one hour.

Comment: That is very nice, thanks a lot!   I was playing with it and let me ask few things more, it's not working when the midnight is passed.    
  0:35:01      22:02:42      (the 0:35:01 is not highlighted.)   Any way to fix it ?

Comment: ok,  i will separate from 0:00 thanks! :)

Comment: Can i add a period of time like  1/24 - 2/24 ?     What i want is to mark with different color the downtimes between 1-2 hours.

Comment: Downtime 1-2hours yellow, downtime 2-3hours red.  Something like   =and(A2<>"",A1>=1/24+A2)     add new formula  =and(A2<>"",A1>=2/24+A2)  with different color. Only highligts yellow color.

Comment: It seems ok but no color change, yellow remains yellow   more than 1hour `=and(A2<>"",A1>=1/24+A2)`  more than 2 hours : `=and(A2<>"",A1>=2/24+A2)` no highlights the cells to red (stay on yellow) where 2hours past.  Any idea?  thank you